# Error while importing Cartopy in python- DLL load failed while importing trace

Tags: python, importerror, cartopy

I have installed `cartopy` using whl package but when I try to import it, it gives me the error-

```
>>> import cartopy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\python38\lib\site-packages\cartopy\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    import cartopy.crs
  File "C:\python38\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 27, in <module>
    import cartopy.trace
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing trace: The specified module could not be found.
>>>
```

I have already install geos on my python, what else is missing here?

Comment: it may needs some C/C++ library - and this you have to install separatelly because it is not Python module. Maybe check documentation if it has some requirements. See [Installation](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/installing.html) - there is `Required dependencies`

Comment: It imports now, thanks